# can someone tell me how to understand the python program below(what do we use __iter__() to do?)

Tags: python

can someone tell me how that can happen?

I have a program like this:

```
class Fib(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 0, 1 

    def __iter__(self):
        return self 

    def next(self):
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b 
        if self.a > 100000:
            raise StopIteration();
        return self.a
```

if I enter :

```
>>> for n in Fib():
...     print n
```

the output is:

```
1
1
2
3
5
...
46368
75025
```

the question is that I have no idea how `__iter__` is related to next(self), and how computer read the program?can someone help me explain this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, there is the concept of iterables and iterators. Loosely, an iterable is anything with an **iter** method. An example is a list. When a for loop is ran on this list, say:

```
for i in range(5):
        print i
```

Python returns an iterator, which automagically calls produces all the result.

Now an iterator(not to be confused with iterables) by itself is any object with an **iter** function and a **next** method.  When this iterator loops, it calls the **next** method on every loop, which basically produces the next output, much like a for loop produces outputs within the range.

When the **next** call reaches the last element, a StopIteration error is raised, ending the loop. This is very analogous to how a for loop works behind the scenes.

In a nutshell, what your code is doing is that it is creating an iterator, and defining what happens every time the iterator wants to fetch the next value i.e the next() method.

Comment: In this case,the __iter__() is called at the fist time,then the loop  calls next() continuely without calling __iter__() again,right? So the __iter__() was just called for one time(at the beginning), then the program only cares about the next() function,right?

Comment: Sort of. When the __iter__is called on the sequence(iterable), it returns a listiterator object. This object is what then keeps calling the next() method until a StopIteration error is raised, meaning that there's no more next value

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://www.diveintopython3.net/iterators.html) out

```
 class Fib:                                        ①
     def __init__(self, max):                      ②
         self.max = max

     def __iter__(self):                           ③
         self.a = 0
         self.b = 1
         return self

     def next(self):                           ④
         fib = self.a
         if fib > self.max:
             raise StopIteration                   ⑤
         self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
         return fib                                ⑥
```

Thoroughly confused yet? Excellent. Let’s see how to call this
iterator:

```
from fibonacci2 import Fib
for n in Fib(1000): 
    print n,
```

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987

Here’s what happens:

The for loop calls Fib(1000), as shown. This returns an instance of the Fib class. Call this fib_inst.
 Secretly, and quite cleverly, the for loop calls iter(fib_inst), which returns an iterator object. Call this fib_iter. In this case,
fib_iter == fib_inst, because the **iter**() method returns self, but
the for loop doesn’t know (or care) about that.
 To “loop through” the iterator, the for loop calls next(fib_iter), which calls the **next**() method on the fib_iter object, which does
the next-Fibonacci-number calculations and returns a value. The for
loop takes this value and assigns it to n, then executes the body of
the for loop for that value of n.
  How does the for loop know when to stop? I’m glad you asked! When next(fib_iter) raises a StopIteration exception, the for loop will
swallow the exception and gracefully exit. (Any other exception will
pass through and be raised as usual.) And where have you seen a
StopIteration exception? In the **next**() method, of course!

Comment: The question has a python-2.7 tag.  Might be helpful to edit your code.

Comment: So rather than `__next__(self)` use `next(self)` and for your print either import print from future or make your print statement 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

Comment: This code isn't mine, it is borrowed from the link, but I have edited it now to match python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Python has iterators, similar to Java's Iterator and C#'s IEnumerable(T).

Read this:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/